# POST method returns 404 when after publishing

Tags: c#, rest, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have ASP.NET Core WebApi. In my controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ListServicesController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public List<CodeList> GetLists()
    {
        // something
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create([FromBody] CodeList codeList)
    {
        if (codeList == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        codesList.Add(codeList);
        return CreatedAtRoute("GetListByName", new { listname = codeList.Name}, codeList);
    }
```

}

When I started it from Visual Studio and send request from POSTMAN, every method works (GET, PUT, POST, DELETE). After I published it on IIS, only GET method works fine. On POST I get **404 Not foud error**

Logs form IIS:

> ********** GET /api/ListServices - 8081 - ********** Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/52.0.2743.116+Safari/537.36 - 200 0 0 6358
>
> ********** POST /api/ListServices - 8081 - ********** Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/52.0.2743.116+Safari/537.36
>   - 404 0 0 78

Comment: You might have to enable the POST verb in IIS

Comment: Yes I thought about that but i think there is another problem. My "publish" function uses old code not the newest one

Comment: Are you able to get POST response as localhost in the server?

Comment: Right now I cant run Web API on IIS Express: I got error 403 Forbidden on Service.exe